# Pandas- How to drop a row or column if they have a certain value most of the times?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe where i have some missing values as "none".

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame ({'Category': (['none',''women','kids']), 'Sales': (['none','none','40']), '# of customers': (['30','none','50']) })`

I want to remove the rows or columns that have most values as 'none'. How to do this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st solution is treat none as character not NaN , the we using `eq` with `sum` (if need drop `row` using `sum(axis=1)`)

```
df.loc[:,df.eq('none').sum().lt(2)]
Out[559]: 
  # of customers Category
0             30     none
1           none    women
2             50     kids
```

2nd solution is assuming your none as `np.nan`  and using `dropna` with `thresh`

```
#df=df.replace('none',np.nan)

df.dropna(axis=0,thresh=2)#here thresh is Require that many non-NA values.
Out[563]: 
  # of customers Category Sales
2             50     kids    40
```

Comment: Thank you it works! i was confused about considering none as NaN but it works fine as other one.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
df.loc[:,(df=='none').sum()<=1]
```

Output:

```
  # of customers Category
0             30     none
1           none    women
2             50     kids
```